# Strange output of "git diff", "git diff HEAD" and "git diff --staged"?

Tags: git, github, version-control, diff, git-diff

There are 3 main `git diff` versions:

> - **`git diff`** - difference between **WORKING DIRECTORY** & **STAGE**
> - **`git diff --staged`** - difference between **HEAD** & **STAGE**
> - **`git diff HEAD`** - difference between **HEAD** & **WORKING DIRECTORY**

Above are the definitions I found almost at every place from various people over the net

I performed certain commits on 3 files in the following order:

> ```
> ce6f5bb (HEAD -> master) 6th commit, file1
> c1c67da 5th commit, file3    
> ea51776 4th commit, file1 file2    
> 001675b 3rd commit, file1 file2    
> ec04f53 2nd commit, file2    
> 21cb6c1 1st commit, file1
> ```
>
> **a. file2** *modified in working direcory*
>   **b. Nothing STAGED for commit**
>   **c. file1** & **file3** *not modified*

---

My Queries are:

### **1. git diff**

```
    git diff
    diff --git a/file2.txt b/file2.txt
    index 21106bf..c755a1e 100644
    --- a/file2.txt
    +++ b/file2.txt
    @@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
     123
     345
     678
    +90.
```

***Even though STAGING AREA WAS EMPTY, why diff was shown?***

---

### **2. git diff HEAD**

```
    git diff
    diff --git a/file2.txt b/file2.txt
    index 21106bf..c755a1e 100644
    --- a/file2.txt
    +++ b/file2.txt
    @@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
     123
     345
     678
    +90.
```

***if LAST COMMIT (HEAD) was related to file1, then why diff of file2 is shown?***
**HEAD doesn't contain anything related to file2 at all**

---

---

### **NOW AFTER STAGING file2** :

### **3. git diff**

> 

It does not show anything!
*(I assume it will only show diff if a file is Staged as well as some **changes apart from** staged version are made in Working Directory too)*
Well if that is the case, then why diff was shown in **1.**

---

### **4. git diff --staged**

```
    git diff
    diff --git a/file2.txt b/file2.txt
    index 21106bf..c755a1e 100644
    --- a/file2.txt
    +++ b/file2.txt
    @@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
     123
     345
     678
    +90.
```

***again if HEAD is pointing to file1, then why diff of file2 is shown?***

---

---

I CREATED THIS IMAGE BELOW **(Note: ANOTHER SCENARIO. Not same as above)**:

for `git diff HEAD`, My guess is that **for every TRACKED FILE**, HEAD will keep traveling backward until it finds the LATEST VERSION OF THAT FILE which was committed, to compare against the one in Working Directory

If we consider a new scenario as below, then for `git diff HEAD`, is it like below what I have assumed?

[image]

Comment: Staging area is never empty, unless you have purposely deleted everything. The staging area defaults to the contents of HEAD. It is essentially what will be commited if you do a commit that allows an "empty" commit, empty in the sense that no changes was done, but never empty in terms of content. The staging area contains the snapshot that will be commited when you do a commit, and therefore it defaults to the contents of HEAD.

Comment: Your diff between HEAD and working directory shows that you have changed the file in your working directory, compared to what is in HEAD. The other two files were unchanged, as per your list of criteria, so they are not shown.

Comment: Your diff between HEAD and STAGED will also show file2 after you have staged that file, because that is the difference between the two.

Comment: The thing that I think confuses you is that when git lists diffs and statuses, it ignores everything that doesn't introduce a change. That's why, even though the staging area *contains* everything that is in HEAD by default, if you ask git to show its contents it will show nothing, because there is no *difference* between HEAD and the staging area.

Comment: As an example of that, do the following. Make sure you have a pristine checkout, no changes in the working folder and none in the staging area. Then modify a file by adding 1 letter to a line. Add this through `git add .`, then do a `git diff --staged`. You will see the change. Then, modify the file again, removing the letter you added. Add it, then do the diff again. It should again show no changes, even though you added something twice.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen ...so does it mean that even if staging area is clean (i.e. no new changes from working directory was added to stage and that everything from stage was already committed in previous commit), it will still default to HEAD?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, my doubt regarding HEAD was... according to my thinking, HEAD only has contents of LATEST committed files (i.e. if only file2 was committed in last commit, then changes of any other TRACKED file, let's say file1 (which was committed in earlier commits...but not latest one) cannot be `diff`-ed with HEAD, because HEAD/LAST COMMIT only has file2)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen, will HEAD(LATEST COMMIT) contain EVERY FILE which is UNDER TRACKING even if not all of TRACKED files were committed in latest commit?

For example, if 10 files are under TRACKING...but let's say the LAST COMMIT was only to 4 of the TRACKED FILES. In that case will the LATEST COMMIT(HEAD) still refer to all the 10 TRACKED FILES for `diff`-ing?

Comment: A commit is always a complete snapshot, but it doesn't make new copies of all files, it references the existing objects in the database for files that didn't change, but you can say that a commit contains all files, not just those that were changed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making one fundamental mistake, and then propagating this mistake into each of your various commands.

The mistake is that you are thinking of a commit as a *change*.  A commit is not a set of changes.  A commit holds a *snapshot* of files.  Moreover, the staging area is never actually *empty*,<sup>1</sup> it just matches the *current commit*, initially.

Files `file1.txt`, `file2.txt`, and `file3.txt` exist in:

- your work-tree, as plain files;
- the index / staging-area, as files in Git's special commit format, ready to be committed; *and*
- each commit.

Each copy of each file can match some other copy of the same file (or any other file), or can be different.

The name `HEAD` selects one particular commit.<sup>2</sup>  At the start of your various tests, the name `HEAD` selected commit `ce6f5bb`.  So there are three files named `file1.txt` available to you and Git at this point, besides those in earlier commits:

- `ce6f5bb:file1.txt`, aka `HEAD:file1.txt`: this copy of `file1.txt` is frozen into a commit and cannot be changed.
- `:file1.txt`: this copy of `file1.txt` is in the index / staging area.  You *can* replace it with a new copy at any time.
- `file1.txt`: this is just an ordinary file.  It's not actually *in* Git at all.  It is a regular file, in your work-tree.

There are also three copies of `file2.txt` and three copies of `file3.txt`.

Running `git diff` with no arguments compares all three files in `HEAD` to all three files in your work-tree.  Only those that are different get mentioned in the output.

Running `git diff --staged` or `git diff --cached` compares all three files in `HEAD` to all three files in the staging area.  Only those that are different get mentioned in the output.

Running `git diff HEAD` compares all three files in `HEAD` to all three files in your work-tree.  Only those that are different get mentioned in the output.

Note that when you use `git log -p` or `git show` to view a commit, Git does a `git diff` of the parent commit's snapshot—its files—vs that commit's snapshot.  Only those files that are different are mentioned in diff you see.  So it *looks like* the commit stores changes, but actually, it just stores a snapshot.

Note, too, that `git status` runs two `git diff`s: one compares `HEAD` vs staging-area, i.e., does a `git diff --staged`, and mentions only the names of files, without showing diffs.  These are the *changes staged for commit* files.  The second diff compares index vs work-tree, i.e., does a `git diff`, and mentions only the name of files.  These are the *changes not staged for commit*.

---

<sup>1</sup>The staging area *can* be totally empty, and is in a fresh repository with no files in it yet and none yet `git add`-ed.  You can also `git rm` every file, which will cause the staging area to be empty.  But normally, it's full of copies of the files from the `HEAD` commit, until you use `git add` to replace those files with ones from the work-tree.

<sup>2</sup>You can ask Git two questions about the special name `HEAD`:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

asks Git *What hash ID does `HEAD` represent, i.e., what is the current commit?*  That's the one `git diff` asks.  Or:

```
git symbolic-ref HEAD
git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name HEAD
```

asks Git *What branch name does `HEAD` represent, i.e., what branch would `git status` say I'm on?*  That question gets asked by `git commit`, for instance, when it goes to update the branch name.

Comment: In essence, if you think of the git staged snapshot as an actual stage, used to produce a frame-by-frame movie, git actually uses a camera to take a full snapshot of the entire stage with everything in it. The "change" that many believe git records would be similar to the manuscript instructions on how to prepare the stage for the next photo. ie. "move the chair 2 inches to the left". Git does not record that, instead it will have 2 full photographs of the stage, one with the chair 2 inches to the left.

Comment: The magic then comes from many of the git commands which will, on demand, work out the differences between those snapshots, so that again it looks like git recorded the changes, but those are actually worked out when needed.

Comment: @torek, so after reading your answer, it makes me think that **`commit ce6f5bb`** will contain all 3 files **(file1, file2, file3)** even though only file1 was `git add`-ed & `git commit`-ed in 6th/LATEST commit ?

Comment: So is it safe to think that **LATEST COMMIT** will contain (**newly TRACKED files if any** + **ALL OF previouly TRACKED FILES of previous commits**)

Comment: Yes: the index / staging-area starts out with all the files from the commit you just checked out or just made. So whatever you replace in it, or add to it, the *remaining* files also go into the next commit. After each `git commit`, the staging area matches the new commit.